# How to compare date with future date in loops using ionic 2?

Tags: loops, date, angular, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2.Here i had calendar,in that it is displaying the present date to future date.I wanted to enable the present date and present date after 2 days.How can i achieve this?

Below is my ts file code what i had tried:

```
var current = new Date();
    current.setHours(0, 0, 0);
    for(var i=current; i<current+2; i++)
    else {
      return true;
    }
    return date < current ;
```

Can anyone please help me..

Comment: for the first time I see a `if(var i=current; i<current+2; i++)` do you think this is right?

Comment: is that a for loop ? or if condition?

Comment: correct it first!! and need more information this three lines of code will not suffice.

Comment: Its a condition, I should enable only 2 days and remaining dates should disable

Comment: What plugin are you using for the calendar? What do you mean by _enable_? The code posted doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @sebaferreras with the help of this: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/blob/master/README.md  I had tried